# How do I phrase my concern so that it suitable for the forum?

Tags: discussion

I want to solicit ideas how to create a theory of a "transcendental space" where nonlinear models for such things as the weather, neurodynamics, semiotics, memetics, love, and Jungian archetypes can exist in such a way that objects implementing the models can influence each other.  These are all subjects that I have found books or research papers described by nonlinear differential equations.  This may be a question of metaphysics, I am not sure.  I want to take the result and apply it to a science fiction book that I care to write. How would I best pose this question to the philosophy forum, if it is even admissible?

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is, concretely? That you want to use the answer for a book need not be a problem, as long as the question is clearly enlarging knowledge of philosophy, and not just about writing. Perhaps you could write up a preliminary version in a quote block in this question, and we can review that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for crafting this into on topic questions is to take specific aspects of your idea and ask what canonical philosophers have addressed them in particular, or at least similar concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that philosophy.meta.stackexchange is a good place to ask "how do I phrase this for philosophy.stackexchange". I can't really make sense of your question exactly as it is, but you could try the following:

> ### What do philosophers of science say about how models interact in theories?
>
> What important considerations are there in constructing a theory of a
>   "transcendental space" [who is the quote from?]. Specifically, how to develop
>   "nonlinear models" [what does this mean?] for such things as the
>   weather, neurodynamics, semiotics, memetics, love, and Jungian
>   archetypes, such that the objects in each model can interact [can you
>   give an example of interaction between models?].
>
> ### Background
>
> All those subjects [weather, neurodynamic, etc.] have been described
>   by nonlinear differential equations, by scholars. I'm asking on
>   philosophy.stachexchange because it may be question about metaphysics, or maybe philosophy of science, I am not sure. What I learn, I hope to apply to a science
>   fiction book that I'm attempting to write.

I'm not promising that the resulting question will not get closed.

You could also try https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ for further help!